# Не работает update user , делаю с помощью диалогового окна, не пойму что не так

Tags: angular, angular2, angular4, angular5, angular10

В этом компоненте вызываю другой компонент который имеет форму для update user

```
export class ListClientComponent implements OnInit {


  clients: Observable<Array<UserProfile>>;

  id: Observable<number>;

  constructor(
    private store$: Store<AdminState>,
    private matDialog: MatDialog
  )
  {
    this.clients = this.store$.pipe(select(selectProfileModel));
    this.id = this.store$.pipe(select(selectDeleteId));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store$.dispatch(new GetListClients());
  }
```

Кнопка где вызываю диалоговое окно

```
editUser(){
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.data = { id: this.id };
    this.matDialog.open(EditUserComponent, dialogConfig);
  }
```

Компонент для обновления юзера

```
export class EditUserComponent implements OnInit {

  editUserForm: FormGroup;
  id: number;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditUserComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private userStore$: Store<UserState>,
  )
  {
    this.editUserForm = new FormGroup({
      "firstName": new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      "lastName": new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      "email": new FormControl("", [ Validators.required, Validators.email ]),
      "password": new FormControl("", Validators.required),
     });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.data.id;
    console.log(this.id);
  }

  save(){
    
    let user: UserProfile = {
      id: this.id,
      firstName: this.editUserForm.controls["firstName"].value,
      lastName: this.editUserForm.controls["lastName"].value,
      email: this.editUserForm.controls["email"].value,
      password: this.editUserForm.controls["password"].value,
      isBlocked: null,
      roles: null
    };

    this.userStore$.dispatch(new EditUser(user));
  }
```

Html код формы обновления

```
<form [formGroup]="editUserForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <div>
        <label>FirstName</label>
        <input 
          name="FirstName" 
          formControlName="firstName"
          required
        />    
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>LastName</label>
        <input 
          name="LastName" 
          formControlName="lastName"
          required
        />    
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Email</label>
      <input 
        name="Email" 
        formControlName="email"
        required
      />    
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Password</label>
      <input
        name="Password" 
        formControlName="password"
        type="password"
        required
      />
    </div>
    
      <button>Save</button>
    
  </form>
```

Ошибка в консоли при нажатии на кнопку сохранить

```
core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'active' of object '[object Object]'
    at QueueScheduler.flush (AsyncScheduler.js:37)
    at QueueAction.schedule (QueueAction.js:14)
    at QueueScheduler.schedule (Scheduler.js:7)
    at QueueScheduler.schedule (AsyncScheduler.js:21)
    at ObserveOnSubscriber.scheduleMessage (observeOn.js:30)
    at ObserveOnSubscriber._next (observeOn.js:33)
    at ObserveOnSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:70)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber._next (innerSubscribe.js:10)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
```

Comment: ` Cannot assign to read only property ` - не могу присвоить значение свойству только для чтения

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я уже пробовал что типа этого ```this.userStore$.dispatch(new EditUser(Object.assign({},{
      id: this.id,
      firstName: this.editUserForm.controls["firstName"].value,
      lastName: this.editUserForm.controls["lastName"].value,
      email: this.editUserForm.controls["email"].value,
      password: this.editUserForm.controls["password"].value,
      isBlocked: null,
      roles: null
    })));```

Comment: @AlexanderChernin и так вот `save(){
    
    let user: UserProfile = {
      id: this.id,
      firstName: this.editUserForm.controls["firstName"].value,
      lastName: this.editUserForm.controls["lastName"].value,
      email: this.editUserForm.controls["email"].value,
      password: this.editUserForm.controls["password"].value,
      isBlocked: null,
      roles: null
    };

    this.userStore$.dispatch(new EditUser(Object.assign({},user)));
  }`

Comment: В ошибке идет речь о свойстве с именем `active` - в примерах его нет нигде, значит ошибка где-то в другом месте